# JQuery UI autocomplete for content in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, bootstrap-modal, jquery-tags-input

I have AJAX generated content in `bootstrap modal` which have elements that using `tags-input` plugin and also `jquery autocomplete` for suggestion.

These tools work properly when the element exist off the modal. So problem occur when I use `bootstrap modal` with `jquery autocomplete`. Means the autocomplete list won't be shown up anymore. But result will come back from server

The tag input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword[]" data-toggle="tag_autocomplete" />
```

JS which call initiator:

```
tag_autocomplete('[data-toggle="tag_autocomplete"]');
```

And eventually my initiator:

```
function tag_autocomplete(selector)
{
    $(selector).tagsInput({
        autocomplete_url: base_url + 'tag/autocomplete',
        width:'auto',
        defaultText:'+',
        minChars: 2,
        maxChars : 50,
        placeholderColor : '#666666'
    });
}
```

Result given from jquery autocomplete:

```
[{tag_id: "3", label: "hossein", value: "hossein"}]
    0: {tag_id: "3", label: "hossein", value: "hossein"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is `z-index` issue, to give auto complete result listing higher priority just add bellow `css` class and add property:

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    z-index: 99999; //Maximum and top of everything (not absolutely :| )
}
```